# Get all entries from Table B which have a relation to multiple entries (given list) from Table A

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have two tables. Table `A` and Table `B`. Both are connected with a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship.

**Table A:**

```
ID
---
1
2
```

**Table B:**

```
ID
---
3
4
```

**Table AB:**

```
ID | A_ID | B_ID
----------------
5  | 1    | 4
6  | 1    | 3
7  | 2    | 3
```

I want to get the list of `ID`s from table `B` which have a relation to **a list of `ID`s of table `A`**.

Example from the above tables:

I want to get all `B`s which have a relation to table `A` `ID` 1 and `ID` 2. I get then `ID` 3 has  to both `ID`s of table `A`.

How could I do this with an SQL query ?

Comment: You want to have Bs that are related to only those As in the list or that are related to at least those As in the list, but possibly more?

Comment: You are giving a list of As as input, right? This has been changed with the last edit, now reading ALL As...

Comment: I would recommend this article about relational division: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to select based on a list of As (not ALL As), then do it like this:

```
SELECT b_id
FROM ab
WHERE a_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY b_id
HAVING COUNT(a_id) = 2
```

Replace `(1,2)` with your list and `2` in the having clause with the number of list items.

If you get your list of As from a subquery you could do it like that (not in MySQL, though...):

```
WITH subquery (
 --subquery code here
)

SELECT b_id
FROM ab
WHERE a_id IN subquery
GROUP BY b_id
HAVING COUNT(a_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subquery)
```

In MySQL you would have to put your subquery code twice and drop the WITH clause.

You could also use a temporary table, which would then lead to selecting ALL As from that temporary table and thus Gordon Linoffs answer...

Comment: the table is just an example

Comment: so your `WHERE a_id IN (1,2)` is not something general.

Comment: That's why I wrote: "Replace ...". This applies when those IDs for A are for example coming from PHP code or something...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did not notice that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by joining and counting:

```
SELECT B_ID
FROM AB JOIN A 
         ON
     AB.A_ID = A.ID
GROUP BY AB.B_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AB.A_ID) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM A);
```

If you know there are no duplicates in `AB` or `A`, you can remove the `distinct` from the `count()`.

Comment: ...and indeed the surrogate key in ab!

Comment: In the last month, you've acquired more rep than I've managed in 2 years. Are you on some kind of mission? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry He is just intellectually generous and kind to help others.

Comment: Can anybody explain to me, why you are joining A here? That doesn't make any sense to me (yet). Is it just to eliminate entries in AB, that are not matched in A?

Comment: @wolfgangwalther . . . It `join`s to `A` to get only the values in A.  This is important for the `count()` in the `having` clause.

Comment: Assuming that there are A_IDs in AB, that are not in A, right? But if AB.A_ID was a foreign key to A, which I would assume in this case, that would be no problem?

Comment: @wolfgangwalther how can the query work without the `JOIN` for the second `COUNT` ?

Comment: @Begueradj The second `COUNT` is within a subquery. No need for the `JOIN` before that.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther So you suggest the query will run successfully without the `JOIN` ? your remark is interesting, I do not see the difference if the query works directly on `AB` without A

Comment: @Begueradj . . . In many cases, you would not need the join on `A` in the inner query.  In particular, if `A` is the reference table and if foreign key references are enforced.

Comment: No, I rather up voted because, even without being able to test your query, it looks too logical to me even if it may not be too perfect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff probably because you didn't answer the original question, which asked for a list of ID's from A. Begueradj edited the question and changed the formatting and a lot of grammar/spelling etc. and accidently changed the meaning of that to "all ID's from A".

Comment: But this actually happened after you answered the question anyways ;)